# WPF control Gridview

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

i am new with WPF please keep that in mind.
I am using a webservice, that returns a list of items and tbh i have web programming background and it was easily done by a Gridview Control, however in wpf there is no Gridview, so i went and made a Listview and created a Gridview out of it. but now its nothing like a Gridview, i mean i cant simply put:

```
GridView.DataSource = bla bla; 
GridView.DataBind();
```

here is my code;

```
WebService.Get get = new WebService.Get();
Gridview.ItemsSource = get.GetMessages("username", "Password", '1',null, 0, '1');
```

Comment: You should look into using the [DataGrid](http://www.wpftutorial.net/datagrid.html)

Comment: Use DataGrid or ListView

Comment: Hey. thanks guys, let me have a look at DataGrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply bind your listview like this

```
ListViewName.ItemsSource = bla bla;
```

You can have a look on the [GridView in WPF](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/gridview-in-wpf/) which gives you a solution as you were looking for

Whereas you can also opt for [DataGrid](http://www.wpftutorial.net/datagrid.html) Instead of GridView inside a ListView

Comment: Thank you! it worked ;) need about 2min to accept your answer :D